# Is it possible to transfer ownership of a question?

Tags: feature-request, questions

If I'm asking a work-related question on StackExchange, I might find that one of my co-workers is more qualified to clarify and expand the question than I am. It might even be the case that the company wants to retain the ability to edit a question once I have left. I'm not sure if this is an appropriate use of the community wiki, as that would allow *anyone* to edit the question, even though it may be fairly specific to our company.

Is there a way to transfer ownership of a question so that someone else can edit it (without having to have their edits approved if they have less than 2,000 reputation), accept answers etc.?

Comment: Why don't simply ask your co-worker to edit it with his/her own account?

Comment: @Alenanno - that doesn't cover the acceptance issue though, and only really works if all parties have > 2,000 reputation.

Comment: @ChrisF If you're talking about the +2 given to the accepted edit, I don't see any room for abuse. Unless I misinterpreted your comment.

Comment: @Alenanno - I was thinking of the **ability** to accept an answer.

Comment: I suppose you could [change your login](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114703/how-can-i-change-my-login-email-address-for-stack-overflow), then give the new login to your co-worker. You do, of course, loose ownership of all questions on that account, not the ownership of only specific questions.

Comment: @ChrisF Ah sorry, I missed that. I don't really think it's a compelling reason for the feature, since after all, he can ask for his co-worker for opinion on which answer to accept. But I'm not actively against the feature (if some better reasons come up).

Answer (score 3):

Interesting idea, but I think the actual cases where it will be needed are too rare to make it practical.

In case of several employees from same company, or company that want to take credit for employee's posts you can create user for the company itself, as far as I can tell it's legit.

Otherwise if you just feel like somebody you know should edit the question let him suggest an edit (it's possible even for anonymous users) then accept the edit. If you know you won't be available for long time and want someone else accept answers on your behalf, create dummy OpenID account just for this purpose, add it to your accounts and give that person the credentials for that account.

Comment: Creating a user for the company does seem like a good idea. I didn't realise you can associate a new OpenID account with your StackExchange account. I assume that would give the other person full access to your account though? Not ideal, but thanks for the idea.

Comment: Personally working with one OpenID but aware that I can add another accounts - so I assume with each you get full access, yes.