# Is it possible to transfer ownership of an answer?

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, answers-as-comments

I often get the result of my questions via a couple of comments (because the other person is too humble to write it as answer?).

In some cases, several comments together make a worthy answer. Thus, I would like to sum up all the comments into the final solution, but feel cheap for getting any reputation for it. I would rather transfer the answer to the poster of all the comments - if he accepts.

Is this possible somehow?

---

Exemplary post: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123157/7635

Related meta-post: [Is it possible to transfer ownership of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147703/is-it-possible-to-transfer-ownership-of-a-question)

---

Update: Making the answer community wiki is a good idea. Since the commentor gets no points and I cannot accept the answer for two days, this is not perfect - but acceptable ;)

Comment: To avoid feeling cheap, write up the summary, and make it community wiki. (If, after gentle poking, the commenter doesn't make their own answer.)

Comment: You can make your answer community wiki so at least you don't get the rep.  That makes it easier for the commenter to then edit.

Comment: Keep in mind that there may be a reason that the answers were left as comments. If someone feels that the question or answer is trivial, he or she may post it as a comment to help you and then vote to close the question.

Comment: As a warning, oftentimes those users know that the comment alone isn't good enough to be an answer.  If you're willing to take the time to flesh it out and they weren't, then that may not be an issue, but often if you aren't adding to it there won't be enough information for it to be an answer.  For example, in some cases the question may be lacking in enough detail to turn the comment that takes you most of the way there into an answer.  Just posting the comment as an answer isn't just rep farming in such a case, it's posting a non-answer.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins You wouldn't vote to close because it's trivial, you'd vote to close because it's incomplete, unclear, etc.  If you just think it's trivial you'd just not answer.

Comment: @Servy My comment alone wasn't good enough to be an answer. Thank you for taking the time to flesh it out by adding the required information. ;) Seriously though, in "Find my typo" questions, the answer is often trivial and easily given via a comment, but the question should not remain open.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I often get the result of my questions via a couple of comments (because the other person is too humble to write it as answer?).

Humble? Lazy. Whoever posts an answer or a half-answer as a comment (I do it all the time) forfeits any rep connected with its contents. It's up for the taking for anyone who wants to take the time to flesh out a proper answer. (Just double-check it *is* a question worth an answer. I sometimes post an answer in a comment, then downvote and closevote with a vengeance because it's so off-topic or otherwise not a good fit.)

Don't worry about this.

Also, you would introduce a potential problem: putting a user's name underneath something that they haven't written. Which can lead to all sorts of trouble.

If you feel really "cheap" about your answer, you can always make it Community Wiki.

Comment: +1, I also do this out of laziness all the time; never out of humbleness!