# Change registered email for SE account

Tags: support, login, email

Is it possible to change the registered email for a StackExchange account so that you can use a new email for login? I have tried to change the email that is in my profile (as shown in picture) but that doesn't disassociate the account from old email that I use to login. Is it even possible or am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: At the top right of your screenshot, you can see "my logins". You can use that link.

Comment: Are you logging in using Stack Exchange or an OAuth/OpenId?

Comment: @jmort253: I'm currently using Yahoo! to login. I'm looking to switch that with Gmail.

Comment: Okay, then changing the registered email is different than changing how you login.  See the "my logins" link in the right of your screenshot?  Registered Email != login

Comment: Would it possible to change the account associations? For example: I'm registered with a different email on a SE site. I want to move that account so that it gets associated with my main email? Because If I change my email for login, it affects all the SE accounts associated with that email.

Comment: Again, email address != Login.  Logins are like the keys to the house, where you might have more than one key. Email address is simply used to send you notifications and is not actually what you use to login. See [Starx's answer for context](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/153556/155826).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I change my login email address for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114703/how-can-i-change-my-login-email-address-for-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 4):

Go to the `my logins` from you profile. There are options to add more login methods and remove previous.

Here is an illustration:

[image]

But if you still cant get what you want contact *team@stackoverflow.com* explaining your needs.