# Email account going to get removed

Tags: support, user-accounts, email

My email account for this account is going to get removed at the end of this week, as it is my school account and I'm leaving school. I would like it be changed to another email address, but I have another account on that email address but its not as good as this account.

Could I change it over from this account to the other? And keep my rankings and everything else?

Comment: You can ask for your accounts to be merged.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist

Comment: This post may help you in what you are looking for: [Change registered email for SE account](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153555/change-registered-email-for-se-account)

Comment: hahaha thanks guys they deleted my old account, as i asked them to it was a old one. Now how can i transfer everything from my school email address to the my home email address? I tried changing my email address like @AzizShaikh said but i still have to login with my school gmail address

Comment: hahahahaha they didn't teach me that :-P, am and yes thanks

Comment: @jmort253 make your answer as a real answer and ill mark it as correct

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't rely on just changing your email; instead, I'd suggest just getting a Gmail account and add that in "my logins". Remember, email != login. They're completely different things, and when you add Gmail as your login, you'll click "Login with Google" to login instead of "Login with Stack Exchange".

This is OAuth, vs just logging in by typing your username and password each time.

Hope this helps! :) And check out that [link from Aziz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153555/change-registered-email-for-se-account). See the "my logins" all the way on the right? That's what you want. :)