# How can I change the email address for my logins in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, login, email

I want to change the email address that I am using to sign in using the Stack Exchange. I tried editing and updating my email address on my profile and saving the changes to all my accounts. Then, I removed the Stack Exchange account from my logins and added it again. But, still it's using my old email address to sign in!
Is there any direct way to change the email address for Stack Exchange Account?

Answer (score 1):

Click on your user name and go to **my logins** which is at the top near the **edit** tab. I believe from there you can configure your login email address. It may take some time to update.

EDIT:
I guess another way you can go about it is making another account with your desired email and then merging your old account to the new one. See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/contact/user-merge

Comment: I have tried that but, it is taking my previous email address as the default. Also, there's no edit option to change the Stack Exchange email address.

Comment: Did you try removing your other logins? I believe you need to remove the other logins so that the only login there is will be the new email address. Also just realized this is a duplicate question http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114703/how-can-i-change-my-login-email-address-for-stack-overflow

Comment: Yes, I've tried that. But, even after removing everything, it's taking the email address that I used for the first time sign up on Stack Exchange. It's not even asking for any email address when I remove all my logins and try to add a Stack Exchange login.

Comment: I updated my answer. I'm not 100% sure but you can try a user merge?