# Is there any way to change my login from a Gmail account to Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid

Currently I am logging in to Stack Overflow with my Gmail account. But at my next company, there is no access for Gmail accounts.

So is there any way to change my Stack Overflow login from a Gmail account to Stack Exchange (or some other provider)?

Obviously, I want to keep all of the reputation that I have earned, and associate it with my new account!

Comment: Also, welcome to Meta! This site is a Q&A site about Stack Overflow itself. Please see the [About](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/about) page for more details, and important information like [how voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: In short, you don't change you just add another login.

Comment: A better duplicate may be *[How can I change my login email address for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114703/how-can-i-change-my-login-email-address-for-stack-overflow/114704#114704)*